# Check values and check if there's difference with awk

Tags: bash, awk

Im trying to compare values gotten from a CSV file that is run several times   already parsed
this is part of the csv file

```
0 20.00GB  
1 20.00GB  
2 20.00GB  
3 20.00GB  
8 21.00GB  
9 21.00GB  
10 21.00GB  
11 21.00GB  
16 22.00GB  
17 22.00GB  
18 22.00GB  
19 22.00GB  
24 23.00GB  
25 23.00GB  
26 23.00GB  
27 23.00GB  
0 44.00GB
```

...

What I want to do is for the same ids check if the second column has a diference in value
This is what i have at the moment

```sh
function checkdif() {
awk -F, '{print $1" "$12}' $1
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you post a sample of the actual csv data? The data you posted only has two columns, and it doesn't appear any rows have values that are the same in both columns.

Comment: And, what happens if there is/isn't a difference? Show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're trying to do is print only the lines where the value in the 2nd column has changed compared to the previous line. This might not be what you're after though, please include an example of the correct output in your question.

You can use an awk variable (in this case `p`) and set it to the value of `$2` as the last thing you do when processing a line.

The first pattern `p != $2 { print }` means that we check whether the 2nd field of the current line is equal to `p`, which is the value from the previous line.

```
awk 'p != $2 { print } { p = $2 }' /tmp/data.txt
```

I.e. given the following (contents of `/tmp/data.txt`)

```
0 20.00GB  
1 20.00GB  
2 20.00GB  
3 20.00GB  
8 21.00GB  
9 21.00GB  
10 21.00GB  
11 21.00GB  
16 22.00GB  
17 22.00GB  
18 22.00GB  
19 22.00GB  
24 23.00GB  
25 23.00GB  
26 23.00GB  
27 23.00GB  
0 44.00GB
```

I'm assuming you want to produce

```
0 20.00GB
8 21.00GB
16 22.00GB
24 23.00GB
0 44.00GB
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` command will do what you are looking for:

> *for the same id check if the second column has different values*

**input1:**

```
$ cat check_id
0 20.00GB  
1 20.00GB  
2 20.00GB  
3 20.00GB  
8 21.00GB  
9 21.00GB  
10 21.00GB  
11 21.00GB  
16 22.00GB  
17 22.00GB  
18 22.00GB  
19 22.00GB  
24 23.00GB  
25 23.00GB  
26 23.00GB  
27 23.00GB  
0 44.00GB
```

id = `0` has 2 different values `20.00GB` and `44.00GB`

**input2:**

```
$ cat check_id2
0 20.00GB  
1 20.00GB  
2 20.00GB  
3 20.00GB  
8 21.00GB  
9 21.00GB  
10 21.00GB  
11 21.00GB  
16 22.00GB  
17 22.00GB  
18 22.00GB  
19 22.00GB  
24 23.00GB  
25 23.00GB  
26 23.00GB  
27 23.00GB  
0 20.00GB
```

All ids have the same value in the 2nd column

**run1:**

```
awk '{b[$1]++;if(b[$1]>1 && a[$1]!=$2){print "id: "$1" has 2 different values "a[$1]" and "$2;test=1;exit};a[$1]=$2}END{if(test==0)print "All identical ids have the same value in the second column"}' check_id 
id: 0 has 2 different values 20.00GB and 44.00GB
```

**run2:**

```
awk '{b[$1]++;if(b[$1]>1 && a[$1]!=$2){print "id: "$1" has 2 different values "a[$1]" and "$2;test=1;exit};a[$1]=$2}END{if(test==0)print "All identical ids have the same value in the second column"}' check_id2
All identical ids have the same value in the second column
```

**Command for readability:**

```
# Rule(s)     
{ 
  #associative array to count the number of occurrences of a specific id    
  b[$1]++
  #when we encounter the element a second time and if the value is different then the previous encountered (stored in a)
  #we print that the ids are different and we stop the execution of awk
  #if you want to print all the ids that have different values then remove the exit
  #the test variable is used to not print the default message in the END clause
  if (b[$1] > 1 && a[$1] != $2) {
    print "id: " $1 " has 2 different values " a[$1] " and " $2
    test = 1
    exit
  }
  #store in the associative array a the pairs id <-> value
  a[$1] = $2
}

# END rule(s)     
END {
  if (test == 0) {
    #if we reach this point it is that all identical ids have the same value in the second column
    print "All identical ids have the same value in the second column"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks  If the file increases in rows the output i got is "id: 0 has 2 different values 20.00GB and 46.00GB" But  I changed the file to have more than 3 differences with the same ID and its not showing. And how to do it to print each uniq id in the csv I mean to output:  id 0 has changed its value N times and    id 1 has increased N times and soo on until id n but

Comment: @DarioValdos: what about doing a `sort -n input | uniq` on the file? If you give me precisely the output that you want for a defined input file, I will be able to tailor my answer to your needs. Could you edit your question and add an input and expected output? Also add a comment here when this is done, so that I get a notification. Thank you.